# Check if video container codec is .mp4 or .mov on iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

In my app a user can select a video from the camera roll with `PHPickerViewController`. I want to read the selected file's video container and/or video codec to see if this is a `.mp4` or `.mov` video. Is there a way to do this?

I could check the file extension of the file but that is not accurate. The user could have renamed the extension at some point. I want to look at the actual media.

Is there a way to get that info from an `AVAsset`? For example: `let avAsset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)`.

Or is there something else to do?

Answer (score 0):

For container, I think the avAsset.availableMetadataFormats shold help. In lldb output:

- mp4: [__C.AVMetadataFormat(_rawValue: org.mp4ra)]
- mov: [__C.AVMetadataFormat(_rawValue: com.apple.quicktime.mdta)]

For codec info, see avAsset.tracks[n].formatDescriptions,  you'll get something like this:

Video:

```
(lldb) po avAsset.tracks[0].formatDescriptions
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <CMVideoFormatDescription> {
    mediaType:'vide' 
    mediaSubType:'avc1' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        codecType: 'avc1'       dimensions: 1080 x 1920 
    } 
    extensions: {{...}}
}
```

Audio:

```
(lldb) po avAsset.tracks[1].formatDescriptions
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <CMAudioFormatDescription> {
    mediaType:'soun' 
    mediaSubType:'aac ' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        ASBD: {
            mSampleRate: 48000.000000 
            mFormatID: 'aac ' 
            mFormatFlags: 0x0 
            mBytesPerPacket: 0 
            mFramesPerPacket: 1024 
            mBytesPerFrame: 0 
            mChannelsPerFrame: 2 
            mBitsPerChannel: 0  } 
        ...
    } 
    extensions: {{...}}
}
```